# align wordpress slideshow in center

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

I have a slideshow of pictures that I am trying to center align. Right now, none of the following work:

```
<center></center>
#slideshow {text-align: center}
```

or setting the style via JS. I have a mockup at http://voicesunited.tk/

How can I center it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
 #slideshow-wrapper { position:relative; margin: 0 auto; }
```

Comment: did you change it in the demo version? I don't see `margin: 0 auto`

Comment: indeed I did, take another look

Comment: add `margin: 0 auto !important;`

Comment: @tekknolagi, still don't see `margin: 0 auto;` on #slideshow-wrapper in the demo site.

Comment: ok that took a really long time to update... thanks, @BrentAnderson and @taro!

Answer (score 0):

`#slideshow-wrapper { margin: 0 auto; }` will work in most browsers.